# What's the best way to supply up-to-date data periodically to an application?

Tags: sql, xcode, web-applications

I would like to make an app in Xcode where users get scored based on football results. For this, I need to update a table of football scores every weekend. What would be the best way to go about this? I assume it would be through SQL queries, but what is the industry standard for grabbing up to date data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is going to be dependent upon your DBMS but a couple ideas to get you started.

- Utilizing SQL server you can created a job and schedule it run on a server a specific schedule, you can write TSQL code to look at CSV files and update your database tables
- You can write an integration package with SSIS and schedule that package to run weekly
- You can write a solution in Python or another scripting language and schedule that to run on your server with windows task manager

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to know where to get started. I ended up using Firebase to send and retrieve data.